# Passport & JWT Authentication & Authorisation

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, authorization, passport.js

Please can anyone look at this code lines... One is working while the other wouldn't work. I am trying to figure out the reason why. in one case, there is a username object in the model for users. while in the other one there is name object as against username. Each model both have a phone object. So in the first case, the user is set up to log in with phone and password.

In this case, the server returns bad request error. Please see code below

```js
//routes/User.js

const express = require('express');
const userRouter = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConfig = require('../passport');
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');
const Todo = require('../models/Transaction');


const signToken = userID =>{
    return JWT.sign({
        iss : "comparelight",
        sub : userID
    },"comparelight",{expiresIn : "1h"});
}

userRouter.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    const { phone,password,name, role, disco, meter, email } = req.body;
    User.findOne({phone},(err,user)=>{
        if(err)
            res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody : "Error has occured", msgError: true}});
        if(user)
            res.status(400).json({message : {msgBody : "Username is already taken", msgError: true}});
        else{
            const newUser = new User({phone,password,name, role, disco, meter, email});
            newUser.save(err=>{
                if(err)
                    res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody : "Error has occured", msgError: true}});
                else
                    res.status(201).json({message : {msgBody : "Account successfully created", msgError: false}});
            });
        }
    });


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
   // passport.js

   const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const User = require('./models/User');

const cookieExtractor = req =>{
    let token = null;
    if(req && req.cookies){
        token = req.cookies["access_token"];
    }
    return token;
}

// authorization 
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest : cookieExtractor,
    secretOrKey : "comparelight"
},(payload,done)=>{
    User.findById({_id : payload.sub},(err,user)=>{
        if(err)
            return done(err,false);
        if(user)
            return done(null,user);
        else
            return done(null,false);
    });
}));

// authenticated local strategy using phone and password
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((phone,password,done)=>{
    User.findOne({phone},(err,user)=>{
        // something went wrong with database
        if(err)
            return done(err);
        // if no user exist
        if(!user)
            return done(null,false);
        // check if password is correct
        user.comparePassword(password,done);

    });
}));
```

But in the other case, the user is set up to sign in with username and password. And this works. Please see code below.

```js
  //routes/User.js

const express = require('express');
const userRouter = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConfig = require('../passport');
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');
const Todo = require('../models/Transaction');


const signToken = userID =>{
    return JWT.sign({
        iss : "comparelight",
        sub : userID
    },"comparelight",{expiresIn : "1h"});
}

userRouter.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    const { username,password,phone, role, disco, meter, email } = req.body;
    User.findOne({username},(err,user)=>{
        if(err)
            res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody : "Error has occured", msgError: true}});
        if(user)
            res.status(400).json({message : {msgBody : "Username is already taken", msgError: true}});
        else{
            const newUser = new User({phone,password,username, role, disco, meter, email});
            newUser.save(err=>{
                if(err)
                    res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody : "Error has occured", msgError: true}});
                else
                    res.status(201).json({message : {msgBody : "Account successfully created", msgError: false}});
            });
        }
    });
});

userRouter.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{session : false}),(req,res)=>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
       const {_id,username,role} = req.user;
       const token = signToken(_id);
       res.cookie('access_token',token,{httpOnly: true, sameSite:true}); 
       res.status(200).json({isAuthenticated : true,user : {username,role}});
    }
});

    // passport.js
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const User = require('./models/User');

const cookieExtractor = req =>{
    let token = null;
    if(req && req.cookies){
        token = req.cookies["access_token"];
    }
    return token;
}

// authorization 
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest : cookieExtractor,
    secretOrKey : "comparelight"
},(payload,done)=>{
    User.findById({_id : payload.sub},(err,user)=>{
        if(err)
            return done(err,false);
        if(user)
            return done(null,user);
        else
            return done(null,false);
    });
}));

// authenticated local strategy using username and password
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username,password,done)=>{
    User.findOne({username},(err,user)=>{
        // something went wrong with database
        if(err)
            return done(err);
        // if no user exist
        if(!user)
            return done(null,false);
        // check if password is correct
        user.comparePassword(password,done);
        
    });
}));
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what's the content of the error message?

Comment: bad request error 400.

Comment: Yes. We know it's a 404. Can you actually console.log the error so we can see exactly why.

Comment: For some reason which i am canniot detect , I ma unable to use phone for sign in

Comment: Console.log() the error please

Comment: this is the error from the server-side  bad request error 400

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: You sure that's what `console.log(err)` have you?

Comment: except I did it wrongly. Yes, that's what is returning. I am using insomnia to test this on my local MongoDB. Please kindly advise where to place the console.log (err) in the code line. So I can check with what I am doing. Thanks

Comment: Right under the first `if(err)` of the 1st piece of code that you said does not work.

Comment: There is a peice of code missing in the first that isnt working. I edited it here and added it but it wasnt refelecting at the time. Here it is... for the login queryuserRouter.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{session : false}),(req,res)=>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
       const {_id,phone,role} = req.user;
       const token = signToken(_id);
       res.cookie('access_token',token,{httpOnly: true, sameSite:true}); 
       res.status(200).json({isAuthenticated : true,user : {phone,role}});
    }
});

Comment: I have done this a million times now and the same response bad request error 400. Which i think its from the server side. user is able to register and immidiately i post in a login request I get a  bad request response. I change to username as against phone and i get to login everytime I try.